# What is the shortest way to modify immutable objects using spread and destructuring operators

Tags: javascript, destructuring, ecmascript-next

I'm looking for a pure function, to modify my immutable state object. The original state given as parameter must stay untouched. This is especially useful when working with frameworks like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) and makes working with [immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) object in javascript much easier. Especially since working with the object spread operator using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is already possible.

I did not found anything better than first copy the object, and than assign/delete the property I want like this:

```
function updateState(state, item) {
  newState = {...state};
  newState[item.id] = item;
  return newState;
}

function deleteProperty(state, id) {
    var newState = {...state};
    delete newState[id];
    return newState;
}
```

I feel like it could be shorter

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Actions on state, where state is considered immutable.

**Adding or Updating the value of a property**:

```
// ES6:
function updateState(state, item) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {[item.id]: item});
}

// With Object Spread:
function updateState(state, item) {
  return {
     ...state,
     [item.id]: item
  };
}
```

**Deleting a property**

```
// ES6:
function deleteProperty(state, id) {
    var newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    delete newState[id];
    return newState; 
}

// With Object Spread:
function deleteProperty(state, id) {
    let  {[id]: deleted, ...newState} = state;
    return newState;
}

// Or even shorter as helper function:
function deleteProperty({[id]: deleted, ...newState}, id) {
    return newState;
}

// Or inline:
function deleteProperty(state, id) {
    return (({[id]: deleted, ...newState}) => newState)(state);
}
```

Comment: Answering your own question seconds after asking?!

Comment: I used the field below the question form to answer it, since I found the solution before posting the question. Since googling for it is pretty hard I put it for everyone here this was.

Comment: But actually, removing a property is also an interesting question. Since setting a property to undefined, does not remove the key, and delete seems not to work inside object definitions ;)

Comment: What you claim to be ES7 is not ES7. Object spread and rest is still a proposal. It will likely come in ES2017.

Comment: Ok thanks, did not looked it up and just followed Ori Drori hint in the comments. I will edit it. - Done, no reference to the ES-whatever more :)

Comment: I wish I could vote for this more. I've come back to this post so many times XD

Comment: deleted is undefined. what am I missing?

Comment: @praHoc idea there was assigning a random value to the key that has to be deleted, you could give a string value "deleted", let  {[id]: "deleted", ...newState} = state; by doing so the <id> property will not be copied to newState

Answer (score 8):

An ES6 solution, that has a bit more support is [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const updateState = (state, item) => Object.assign({}, state, { [item.id]: item });
```

Comment: Sure, that's the same in ES5 style.

Comment: Sorry have to update the question then. Using babel es6 + plugin for this ;) Got a little confused.

Comment: Actually arrow functions are available only in ES6, so this snippet is ES6.

Answer (score 2):

**In a Map Function**

To do this process within a map function (remove an attribute and add a new attribute on each object), given an array of objects -

```
const myArrayOfObjects = [
    {id: 1, keyToDelete: 'nonsense'},
    {id: 2, keyToDelete: 'rubbish'}
];
```

Delete the attribute `keyToDelete`, and add a new key `newKey` with the value `"someVar"`.

```
myArrayOfObjects.map(({ keyToDelete, ...item}) => { ...item, newKey:'someVar'});
```

Updating the array to

```
[
    {id: 1, newKey:'someVar'},
    {id: 2, newKey:'someVar'}
]
```

See [this great post](https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90) for more information on the deletion method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing boilerplate code (as answered above: `(({[id]: deleted, ...state}) => state)(state)`) which is hard to read, you could use some library to do the same:

- https://github.com/cah4a/immutable-modify
- https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper
- https://github.com/M6Web/immutable-set
- https://github.com/bormind/immutable-setter

For example:

```
import {remove} from 'immutable-modify'

function updateState(state, item) {
   return remove(state, item.id)
}
```

It's also supports any nested updates:

```
import {set} from 'immutable-modify'

function updateState(state, item) {
   return set(state, 'user.products', (products) => ({
      ...products,
      items: products.items.concat(item),
      lastUpdate: Date.now()
   }))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
const { id, ...noId } = state;
```

And test:

```
console.log(noId);
```

Answer (score -2):

Removing item from an array, just use filter ;)

```
CASE 'REMOVE_ITEM_SUCCESS':

      let items = state.items.filter(element => element._id !== action.id);

      return {
            ...state, 
            items
      }
```